# Inner Join on Hive generating IndexOutOfBound error

Tags: hive

I have two tables that I'm trying to `join` with

```
drop table if exists test.thing_bid;

create table if not exists test.thing_bid as
select
    pq.nr,
    pq.id_l,
    sna.id_c,
    sna.num_total,
    pq.ref_month
from
    stage.sna sna
join
    stage.snapshot_monthly pq
on
    (pq.nr = sna.ph and pq.ref_month = sna.ref_month)
```

But I'm getting the error

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0 (state=42000,code=40000)
```

That is not very helpful. The types of the fields are the same on each table. Why is this error occurring?

Comment: The Hive version is 0.14, if it helps.

Comment: Does sna or snapshot_monthly use ORC file format?

Comment: Both are in ORC format.

Comment: you may want to look up your delimiters in your table. it could happen your table might be breaking somewhere because of that.

Comment: Can you change the Source ORC to RC file format? There is a known bug on this AFAIK. You can try using Parquet file format as well. It is similar to ORC and performs as well.

Comment: Thanks. Right now we can't change the format, but I'll keep that in mind. We are familiar with Parquet, too, and will try to change formats.